# Getter in the generic class

Tags: c#

I have a generic class, which looks like this:

```
// K is key, T is type of content
class myClass<K, T>
{
    private List<T> items;
    private Dictionary<K, T> itemMap;
}
```

getter by key :

```
public T get(K index)
{
    if (this.itemMap.ContainsKey(index))
    {
        return this.itemMap[index];
    }
    else
    {
       // no key found
        return default(T); 
    }
}
```

When I use this simple class as T (using id as key in itemMap) :

```
class myConcreteT 
{
    int id;
    int otherParameter;
}
```

what is the correct way to find instance of this class in items List by *otherParameter*? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: If you're trying to find the item in a collection given a key then you should be using a dictionary (or other comparable structure) not a `List`.

Comment: Where do you want to find the instances at all? If in `myClass` it's not possible because it does not know that `myConcreteT` has an `id` field (which must be `public` anyway if you want to access it from outside).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A way to find item in list/dictionary is just Where:

```
  myConcreteT search = ...
  var item = items.Where(x => x.otherParameter == search.otherParameter)
       .FirstOrDefault();
```

If you want "generic" version you'd pass predicate to your search function along with the value like:

```
  T SearchByItem(T search, Func<T, T, bool> matches)
  {
     return items.Where(x => matches(x,search))
       .FirstOrDefault();
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want your generic type T to have know properties then you will have to add a constraint to your generic class definition. If that is not possible then the comparison algorithm will have to be supplied by the caller as in @Alexei Levenkov's answer

```
public interface IKnownProperties
{
   int id {get;}
   int otherParameter { get; }
}

// K is key, T is type of content
class myClass<K, T> where T:IKnownProperties
{
    private List<T> items;
    private Dictionary<K, T> itemMap;
} 

class myConcreteT : IKnownProperties 
{
    int id {get;set;}
    int otherParameter {get;set;}
}
```